# Coger una cadena texto entre dos palabras PHP

Tags: php, string, regex, php7, preg-match

Tengo este texto:

```
INFRACCIÓ LLEI DE SEGURETAT VIÀRIA ART. 40-2 TIPO INF.: LLEU
ESTACIONAR EN LLOC HABILITAT PER L'AUTORITAT MUNICIPAL AMB LIMITACIÓ HORÀRIA ,AMB
CARÈNCIA DEL TÍTOL O BITLLET D'ESTACIONAMENT QUE HO AUTORITZA. (ART. 94.2.BRGC)
LUIS BOLINCHES COMPAÑ (ESCULTOR) NUM. 11
VEHICLE MATRICULA: 8134LRG - MARCA:FIAT FIAT 500
AGENT: 93 REF: MU 2021 37 24617644 - 3 DATA: 27/08/2021 H.:09:28
```

Me gustaria extraer el texto que está entre este caracter `")"` y la palabra `"VEHICLE"`, lo que esta dentrode estas condiciones puede cambiar su longitud osea puede ser otra frase.

No se si puede hacer con una expresion regular, creo que sí pero no sé cómo.

Comment: Qué paréntesis? El que cierra BRGC) o el que cierra ESCULTOR)?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El que cierra BRGC

Answer (score 0):

Puedes solucionarlo con una función

```html
function obtenerCadena($contenido,$inicio,$fin){
        $r = explode($inicio, $contenido);
        if (isset($r[1])){
            $r = explode($fin, $r[1]);
            return $r[0];
        }
        return '';
    }
```

La utilizas de la siguiente manera :

```html
$frase = "INFRACCIÓ LLEI DE SEGURETAT VIÀRIA ART. 40-2 TIPO INF.: LLEU
    ESTACIONAR EN LLOC HABILITAT PER L'AUTORITAT MUNICIPAL AMB LIMITACIÓ HORÀRIA ,AMB
    CARÈNCIA DEL TÍTOL O BITLLET D'ESTACIONAMENT QUE HO AUTORITZA. (ART. 94.2.BRGC)
    LUIS BOLINCHES COMPAÑ (ESCULTOR) NUM. 11
    VEHICLE MATRICULA: 8134LRG - MARCA:FIAT FIAT 500
    AGENT: 93 REF: MU 2021 37 24617644 - 3 DATA: 27/08/2021 H.:09:28";



    $texto = obtenerCadena($frase,"(ART. 94.2.BRGC)","VEHICLE");
    var_dump($texto);
```